# what is the command to docker image prune based on image/repo name

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I want to prune images based on image/repo name , lets say i have unused images named after postgres, postgres:v2, nginx and nginx:v2 now i want to prune all images based on image name that is postgres not nginx

```
docker image prune -a -f | grep postgres
```

but pruning all images i.e postgres and nginx , Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There are probably multiple ways to do it, but I have a defined function that accepts a string as an argument, and deletes all images that have this partial string in their name:

```
$ drmi() { docker images --format "{{.Repository}}:{{.Tag}}" |grep $1 | xargs docker rmi -f; }
```

Then you can do:

```
$ drmi postgres
```

In reality, I am using a [bash alias manager](https://github.com/DannyBen/alf-conf/blob/a4d2b9ed4ea903b0c003dae32f552a72fac21124/alf.conf#L58) (that I developed, full disclosure) and have many aliases for docker, so I can do things like:

```
$ d rmi postgres
$ d size    # to show images sorted by size, so you can find delete candidates
```

[Here](https://github.com/DannyBen/alf-conf/blob/a4d2b9ed4ea903b0c003dae32f552a72fac21124/alf.conf#L58) is how I define the `d rmi` function, along with other useful functions.

Answer (score 0):

`docker image prune` doesn't support passing the image name with the command.

You can use the `docker rmi` command instead on the output of `docker images` command to delete specific docker images:

```
docker rmi $(docker images postgress -q)
docker rmi -f $(docker images postgress -q)  # forceful deletion
```